# Children candies Hackerrank challenge : optimising the solution

Tags: javascript, algorithm, optimization

I am trying to solve an [hackerrank](https://www.hackerrank.com) challenge in JavaScript, and although for most of the test instances my solution performs quite well, I keep getting a timeout for some of them (Hackerrank has it set for 10 seconds for JavaScript challenges). The problem is described below:

> There are N children standing in a line. Initially the i-th child has a[i]
>   candies. Some of the children have more candies than others. You have
>   to make sure that every student has the same number of candies. In one
>   operation you can tell one of the children to give a single candy to
>   the left neighbour, or to the right one. How many operations do you
>   need to make sure every student has same number of candies? Print the
>   minimal possible number of operations. The input is a multiline
>   string, where the first line contains a single integer N, and the next
>   line contains N space separated integers.

I solved this problem by calculating which number of candies should be given to each and every kid, and then iterate the array containing the number of candies, either grabbing candies from the rightmost positions (in case the child wouldn't have enough), or passing candies to the right position (in case the child would have more than needed)

This is the code I used for the challenge:

```
function processData(input) {
    let tmp = input.split(/\n| /),
        n = tmp[0]    

    tmp.shift()  // remove first element from tmp (the N variable)

    let s=0, a = tmp.map(function(ai) {novo=parseInt(ai, 10);s+=novo;return(novo)}),
        obj = s/n, ops = 0

    for(var i=0; i<n; i++) {

        if(a[i] > obj) {
            let moved = a[i]-obj
            a[i]-=moved
            a[i+1]+=moved
            ops+=moved
        }
        else {
            for(var j=i+1; a[i] != obj; j++) {


                if(a[j]===0) {
                    ops++
                }
                else {
                    let moved = Math.min(a[j], obj-a[i])
                    a[i]+=moved
                    a[j]-=moved
                    ops+=moved
                }
            }        
        }

        //console.log(a)
    }

    console.log(ops)
}
```

Any idea on what is the problem?

How would you optimise my code?

Link to the challenge : https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/coc1/challenges/candies-1

**EDIT**
After some optimisations, my solution now fails 3 of the test cases (the same ones it was failing before due to timeout). It was not a performance issue

Comment: Try to copy the exact problem statement. The second sentence of your problem description has a very different meaning from the one in challenge.

Comment: Edited! Thanks for noticing that error

Comment: The main problem is that you have three nested loops making the runtime something like O(n^3). You should be able to do it in one pass of the data. First calculate the number of candies that each child will eventually end up with. Then scan over the chlidren. Think about it this way: If the first child has k candies below average these k candies have to be transported there. So you will need at least k moves. Now go to the next child, can you get them from there, maybe partially? If not you will need an additional k moves for the first child and on top the candies that child 2 is missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is, how many moves do you need to have an avarage count for each children.

> For example take this line of children,
>
> ```
> 1  4  2  7  1
> ```
>
> where you start with the first children and look how much items it has and how many items it should have. Take the (absolute) difference for counting the moves and give the first child the average. The next children gets the delta of the first children. In this case after giving two items, it has then two items.
>
> Then look at the next children in the line. Repeat the above and you get the count of moves for all children in a single loop.
>
> ```
>    children     moves 
> --------------- -----
>  1  4  2  7  1     2
> <3  2> 2  7  1     1
>  3 <3  1> 7  1     2
>  3  3 <3  5> 1     2
>  3  3  3 <3  3>
> --------------- -----
>                    7
>
> <x  y> denotes a group of changing values
> ```
>
> Example 2
>
> ```
>    children     moves 
> --------------- -----
>  7  4  2  1  1     4
> <3  8> 2  1  1     5
>  3 <3  7> 1  1     4
>  3  3 <3  5> 1     2
>  3  3  3 <3  3>
> --------------- -----
>                   15
> ```

```js
function processData(input) {
    var [length, ...values] = input.split(/\\n|\s/),
        i,
        moves = 0,
        value = 0,
        sum = 0,
        avg;
        
    for (i = 0; i < +length; i++) sum += +values[i];
    avg = sum / length;

    for (i = 0; i < length - 1; i++) {
        value += +values[i];
        moves += Math.abs(value - avg);
        value -= avg;
    }
    
    return moves;
}

console.log(processData('5\n1 4 2 7 1')); //  7
console.log(processData('5\n7 4 2 1 1')); // 15
console.log(processData('3\n1 2 3'));     //  2
```

Comment: Oops this is the same solution as mine +1, it is not the same as @binte's.